# tkinter - grid_slave configurate a slave

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I have a grid_slave can I somehow config him?

I'm doing something like this:

```
...
self.numbts = Frame(root)
self.numbts.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, padx=4, pady=4)

Button(self.numbts, text = "button",...).grid(row = 1, column = 3, ...)

self.numbts.grid_slaves(1,3) #i get from print this: [<tkinter.Button object .22182224.22183024>]
```

i want to do something like this:

```
x = self.numbts.grid_slaves(1,3)
x.config(text = "Button")
```

or

```
self.numbts.grid_slaves(1,3).config(text = "Button")
```

Thank you for all answers. :)

Comment: What happens when you do what you want to do? In your code you aren't putting the button in `self.numbts`, is that intentional? If so, why is that relevant to the problem?

Comment: i'm putting a Button to the numbts Button(self.numbts, text="button", ...) i just didn't write it in this example. If i do "self.numbts.grid_slaves(1,3).config(text = "Button")" i get an error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'config' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grid_slaves()` with no arguments will return a list. Each element is a widget that you can configure. For example:

```
widgets = self.numbts.grid_slaves()
widgets[0].config(text="Button")
```